# How do I get an xml property using the react?

Tags: javascript, json, xml, reactjs

And a part of the xml I need

```
<content type="application/xml">
        <m:properties>
            <d:DirectReports m:type="Collection(Edm.String)" />
            <d:DisplayName>teste</d:DisplayName>
            <d:Email>teste</d:Email>
            <d:IsFollowed m:type="Edm.Boolean">false</d:IsFollowed>
            <d:LatestPost m:null="true" />
            <d:Title>CONSULTOR TECNOLOGIA</d:Title>
        </m:properties>
    </content>
```

I have a React application and I need to get the Title property of xml and play in a div, I do not know if I'm getting the xml get correctly. It must be simple, but I can not do it. Who to help will be grateful

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-xml-parser

Comment: @RobertHarvey This my xml is external, do you know if it works?

Comment: I don't see why not.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I cannot add comments yet. Roger's package looks good.

**Here is 1 I have used:**
https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml-js

Works nice if you create a util function with this to handle the promise and return the JSON.

Comment: @MatheusAraujo - What do you mean external service? XML is a format, whether it comes from internal to the application or external does not matter in regards to parsing.